# Sort array with custom object by date

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have an NSArray that contains custom Object (ItemThread) and I have to order this array using a property of these objects (a Date but is a NSString). The item to order are into an array called  "threadList" that contains my custom data (ItemThread). So I try to use:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
 sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"detail" ascending:NO];     
 NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
 NSArray *sortedArray = [threadList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

But it doesn't work because the property `detail` is a date but not an NSDate, is an NSString. Do you have solutions?

Or I have tried to use

```
 NSMutableArray *threadDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for (int i = 0; i<threadList.count; i++) {
       ItemThread *_thr = [threadList objectAtIndex:i];
       [threadDateArray addObject:_thr.detail];
 }
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
 [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

  NSMutableArray *dateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (NSString *dateString in threadDateArray) {
       NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
       [dateArray addObject:date];
  }
  NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
  NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
  NSArray *reverseOrder = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

In this way I have an array of NSDate that is correctly ordered. But now, how can I use this order to order my threadList array of custom objects?

Comment: At the point when you create your custom object why don't you store the date as an NSDate, that way the first sort type you posted would work.

Comment: Because my custom object is stored in coreData and I have to use the NSString type to store it.

Comment: CoreData supports NSDate

Comment: Yes but I take the date from a server and comes to me like NSString

Comment: But in your second sort option you are going through the code to convert that value to a date. Use that code when you populate the CoreData in the first place, then it will be a date